# Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() : java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have following code to run a function in another thread:

```
Button buttonb = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.buttonb);
    buttonb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        …
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Thread thread = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        matrixOperation(sourcePhoto);
                    }
                };
                thread.start();

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        …

        }
    });
```

But on running i am getting this error:

```
Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

I searched and found that one reason for this error is “You cannot execute an AsyncTask from a background thread. See the "Threading Rules" section of” But this is not background thread I am calling it from my Main Activity.

Please tell me how I can fix this.

Comment: You'r starting a thread. So it IS running in a background thread then.

Comment: What does `matrixOperation()` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Handler` class uses `Looper`s to perform its scheduling, and threads that have just been created does not have an associated looper – hence the error.

As you have not provided the handler creation code, I'm assuming you want to call code on the main thread. In this case, create the `Handler` as follows:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

Anything scheduled to run on that `Handler` will execute on the main `Looper`, which is running on the main thread.

Comment: how do i utilize the `handler` object?

Comment: Just pass a `Runnable` to its `post` method